# deployed cassandra datastax enterprise and got java.lang.AssertionError

Tags: deployment, cassandra, datastax-enterprise

I am trying to deploy the cassandra datastax enterprise 4.5.1 on my cluster, and I always got java.lang.AssertionError, the log is as below:

```
 INFO [main] 2014-10-13 06:01:03,142 CLibrary.java (line 63) JNA not found. Native methods will be disabled.
 INFO [main] 2014-10-13 06:01:03,155 CacheService.java (line 105) Initializing key cache with capacity of 100 MBs.
 INFO [main] 2014-10-13 06:01:03,167 CacheService.java (line 117) Scheduling key cache save to each 14400 seconds (going to save all keys).
 INFO [main] 2014-10-13 06:01:03,169 CacheService.java (line 131) Initializing row cache with capacity of 0 MBs
 INFO [main] 2014-10-13 06:01:03,177 CacheService.java (line 141) Scheduling row cache save to each 0 seconds (going to save all keys).
 INFO [main] 2014-10-13 06:01:03,471 ColumnFamilyStore.java (line 249) Initializing system.schema_triggers
 INFO [main] 2014-10-13 06:01:03,522 ColumnFamilyStore.java (line 249) Initializing system.compaction_history
 INFO [SSTableBatchOpen:1] 2014-10-13 06:01:03,547 SSTableReader.java (line 223) Opening /apps/datastax-enterprise/9161/ddata/data/system/compaction_history/system-compaction_history-jb-4349 (163599 bytes)
ERROR [SSTableBatchOpen:1] 2014-10-13 06:01:03,565 SSTableReader.java (line 233) Cannot open /apps/datastax-enterprise/9161/ddata/data/system/compaction_history/system-compaction_history-jb-4349; partitioner org.apache.cassandra.dht.RandomPartitioner does not match system partitioner org.apache.cassandra.dht.Murmur3Partitioner.  Note that the default partitioner starting with Cassandra 1.2 is Murmur3Partitioner, so you will need to edit that to match your old partitioner if upgrading.
 INFO [Thread-1] 2014-10-13 06:01:03,569 DseDaemon.java (line 477) DSE shutting down...
ERROR [Thread-1] 2014-10-13 06:01:03,635 CassandraDaemon.java (line 199) Exception in     thread Thread[Thread-1,5,main]
java.lang.AssertionError
at org.apache.cassandra.gms.Gossiper.addLocalApplicationState(Gossiper.java:1263)
at com.datastax.bdp.gms.DseState.setActiveStatus(DseState.java:171)
at com.datastax.bdp.server.DseDaemon.stop(DseDaemon.java:478)
at com.datastax.bdp.server.DseDaemon$1.run(DseDaemon.java:384)
```

Dose anynone know this or maybe give me any infomation? Any answer will be appreciated

Comment: partitioner org.apache.cassandra.dht.RandomPartitioner does not match system partitioner org.apache.cassandra.dht.Murmur3Partitioner.  
Note that the default partitioner starting with Cassandra 1.2 is Murmur3Partitioner, so you will need to edit that to match your old partitioner if upgrading.

Comment: @RussS Thanks for reminding, I have modified that and will try it agiam later

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, as @RussS said, this is because the partitioner doesn`t match, we should use **partitioner: org.apache.cassandra.dht.RandomPartitioner** in cassandra.yaml